# Unable to use es6 export keyword in Chrome63

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, es6-modules, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use the `export` keyword in my `test.js` file. The `test.js` file is pretty simple.

```
const foo = Math.PI;
export { foo };
```

And I am using `karma` to do the testing. My `Chrome` version is greater than `61` as seen in the log below. The `export` syntax is full supported in chrome versions greater than 61 so the above code should work but it fails.

```
$ karma start --browsers Chrome
01 10 2017 12:29:37.346:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
01 10 2017 12:29:37.350:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
01 10 2017 12:29:37.357:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
01 10 2017 12:29:38.288:INFO [Chrome 63.0.3205 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)]: Connected on socket PV-MAe-R6vm4JntCAAAA with id 24009783
Chrome 63.0.3205 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
  at test/test.js:2
```

Any suggestions why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the keywords that are specific to ES modules (`import` and `export`) to be properly interpreted, the script should be loaded as module. And Karma [doesn't do that](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2684).

Even if Karma would support it, real-world applications rely on things that can be properly handled only by bundlers, such as NPM packages consisting of CommonJS/UMD modules.

Currently tests that involve ES modules should be transpiled in Karma.

Comment: Thank you @estus for the answer. Is there some other testing tool that supports ES6 modules ? I am not really tied to karma and I will just prefer to stick to ES6 for everything without adding a transpiler if that's possible. I am not familiar with the relative capabilities of `Karma`, `Mocha`, `QUnit` are. Does any of them support ES6 fully. Also I guess I don't really understand which bundler to use. Is `Rollup` capable of transpiling?

Comment: Mocha doesn't offer a runner for browsers. There is Jest, but it's unlikely that will support native modules by design. Again, it's impractical because the app will choke on third-party modules, and there are zero chances to stub/mock/process modules when doing this natively. You can use Rollup or Webpack to transpile and bundle the app, but the truth is that full-featured test runner (which Karma is) handles this for you. Karma does that [via a plugin](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor).